# Change Bundle Id for Firebase Crashlytcs on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

We want to change the Bundle Id used by Crashlytics on Xcode. We are using Swift and the Framework Version 3.9.3 (128).

So far the instance always uses the bundle id from the App but we want to separate the Staging from Production crashes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You will not be able to preserve reporting to the same dashboard for both apps. However, if you are willing to use two separate dashboards, all you need to do is build and run the new bundle ID in the simulator. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The thing is that we want to change the Bundle ID automatically according to the Build Configuration on the Xcode schema settings, I mean, if I run the simulator with _Release_ selected on Build Configuration, Crashlytics should use the Bundle ID **com.appID** but if _Debug_ is selected, then **com.appID.staging** should be used. All of this without change the Bundle ID specified on the Xcode target setting.